# How to get url data in $_get['a'] in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am passing my url with values from javascript to PHP like:

```
<script>

    var a= "10-test(8 2) DVI-A Male";
    var b= "8-test(6 2) DVI-A Male";
    var test = a.replace("+", "%2B"); 
    var test1 = b.replace("+", "%2B"); 
    window.open("listing.php?cond=true" + "&a=" + (test.replaceAll("%", " ")) + "&b=" + test1.replaceAll("%", " "));
</script>
```

I have a URL like

```
localhost://listing.php?cond=true&a=10-test%20(8+2)%20DVI-A%20Male&b=test2%20Male
```

I want to get the data of a & b
For this I used :

```
<?php
    $a = $_GET["a"];
    $b = $_GET["b"]; ?>
```

But I got the result like

```
$a = 10-test(8 2) DVI-A Male
```

I lost my + symbol in my result.
How can I get the result like:

```
10-test(8+2) DVI-A Male
```

Comment: You used `%20` for the `space` but `+` is also a space, you need to use `%2B` for the `+`.  `urlencode`

Answer (score 0):

The `+` sign represents a space in URLs. It will need to be encoded as `%2B`

```
localhost://listing.php?cond=true&a=10-test%20(8%2B2)%20DVI-A%20Male&b=test2%20Male
```

Should return a `$_GET` array like:

```php
array(
  'cond' => 'true',
  'a' => '10-test (8+2) DVI-A Male',
  'b' => 'test2 Male',
)
```

Comment: I tried with this, But, I didn't get it, because I passed this URL value from a script like 
var test = a.replace("+", "%2B");

window.open("listing.php?cond=true" +  "&a=" + (test.replaceAll("%", " ")) + "&b=" + b.replaceAll("%", " "));

Comment: Can you plz check the full code. I added my script and PHP codes.